# Creating an array of objects in javascript, then fetching properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, 2048

so I'm trying to recreate 2048 in javascript right now and having some trouble. Basically, my idea was to create the grid as an array of 16 objects that take coordinates and a boolean variable of whether it is filled with a tile or not.

```
  var blocks = [];

  var block = function block(xcord, ycord, filled) {
    this.xcord = xcord;
    this.ycord = ycord;
    this.filled = filled;
};

function createGrid(){
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){

      blocks.push(block(i+1, j+1, false));

      }
    }
}
```

However when I try to print the assigned values of the blocks, it says they are undefined

```
console.log(blocks[0].String(xcord));
```

Gives me

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'String' of undefined
    at raqixa.js:180:47
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.12.min.js:1:13891
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.12.min.js:1:10820"
```

Comment: In addition to the below answers you should capitalize the name of the constructor function by convention ... like Block. Plus what's the point of double name assignment..?

Comment: Capitalized it. What do you mean by double name assignment? Calling both the variable and function "block"?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do that as a common practice. For your fingers good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword with the code you have, and also change the way you access the blocks array check it out:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/zeqimoj/1/edit?js,console)

```
  var blocks = [];

  var block = function block(xcord, ycord, filled) {
    this.xcord = xcord;
    this.ycord = ycord;
    this.filled = filled;
};

function createGrid(){
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      blocks.push(new block(i+1, j+1, false));
      }
    }
}

createGrid();
console.log(blocks);
console.log(blocks[0].xcord);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple add a new before block.

```
blocks.push(new block(i + 1, j + 1, false));
```

working example: http://jsbin.com/filerocoso/1/edit?js,output

To access the variable use:

`console.log(blocks); 
console.log(blocks[0].xcord); // first item in array, property xcord`

Edit: Jordon beat me to it, also updated example and show correct access of array property.